# Using epsilon-delta function, prove that $\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\:1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm still learning, therefore I'm less confident about my answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong-

Given, $L=1 , c=1$

$\left|f\left(x\right)-L\right|<\epsilon $

$\left|\frac{1}{x}-1\right|<\epsilon $

$\left|x-1\right|<\frac{1}{\epsilon }$

Let, $\frac{1}{\delta }=\epsilon$

Therefore,

$\left|x-c\right|<\delta $

$\left|x-1\right|<\delta \:$

$\left|\frac{1}{x}-1\right|<\frac{1}{\delta }=\epsilon$

Comment: How do you go from $\left\lvert\frac1x-1\right\rvert<\varepsilon$ to $\lvert x-1\rvert<\frac1\varepsilon$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I reciprocated the entire expression. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes. For instance, $\lvert2-1\rvert<3$ is true, but $\left\lvert\frac12-1\right\rvert<\frac13$ is false.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0) Let $|x-1|<1/2$;

Then $x>1/2$;

1)$|1/x-1|=\frac{|x-1|}{|x|} <2|x-1|$.

2)$\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose $\delta =\min (1/2, \epsilon/2)$.

3) Then $|x-1|<\delta$ implies

$|1/x-1| <2|x-1| \lt 2\delta \le \epsilon$.

Comment: What does this expression means- δ=min(1/2,ϵ/2) ? I'm still unable to get you.

Comment: Kliendester.  It means : given \epsilon. Chosse your $\delta = \min (1/2,\epsilon/2)$, i.e. the smaller of the 2 numbers.1) Case 1 : $1/2 <\epsilon/2$, recall $\epsilon >0$ is some number given; Case 2: $1/2>\epsilon/2$. Look at 3) in the answer $|x-1| <2|x-1| <2\delta <\epsilon$ Go through this line for each case. Your thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation- now it's clear. Can you please suggest me a book which deals this topic with much clarity?

Comment: Kliendester. You need to work through a few similar problems, and learn it by doing. Here a link you may want to check out:  https://www.google.com/search?q=lang+undergraduste+analysis&oq=lang+undergraduste+analysis+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.19788j0j7&client=ms-android-motorola&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8 . It is Serge Lang Undergraduate Analys. Are you self-studying or in a College?

Comment: thank you for the recommendation. I'm enrolled in distance education, thus self-studying everything.

Comment: Some  universities' Analysis courses are available online, free downloads, possibly  S.Lang's text is available too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106828/discussion-between-kliendester-and-peter-szilas).